# Adding TD Dynamically Using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a method that adds an image to a TD and attaches the click event to the image. I am dynamically building a row and wanted to attach the TD image column to my row.

```
$("<tr></tr>").append(addActionColumn($("<td></td>")));
```

And here is my addActionColumn method:

```
function addActionColumn(td) {



    var actionImage = document.createElement("img");
    $(actionImage).attr("src", "../Images/cross_red.JPG");

    // delete the row
    $(actionImage).click(function() {

        $(td).parent().remove();

     });


    $(td).append(actionImage);
}
```

For some reason the TR never gets the image column attached to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function doesn't return the td element you create.

Comment: Thanks! I am having a case of the Fridays!

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this:

```
var td = $('<td />');
$('<img />').addClass('close-button').prop('src', '../Images/cross_red.JPG').appendTo(td);

$('<tr />').append(td).appendTo('#your_parent_element');

$('.close-button').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you are trying to `.append` the result of the `addActionColumn` which is null because you are not returning a value in the function.

try something like this at the end of the function:

```
return $(td);
```